# Setting up Postfix/SMTP Auth service using ldap

Tags: email, authentication, postfix-mta, smtp-auth

How to configure the server to allow users to authenticate against the postfix and to send mail from any client software.  I think I am missing something small but I need HELP.  I have been working on this on and off for about 8 weeks now and cannot figure out my issue.

**Telnet test from remote machine (My Laptop)**

```
imac:~ jtolson $ echo -ne '\0sogo1\0sogo' | openssl enc -base64
AHNvZ28xAHNvZ28=

imac:~ jtolson $ telnet 10.1.2.130 25
Trying 10.1.2.130...
Connected to 10.1.2.130.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 *********************************
EHLO tcusit.com
250-tcusit.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN AHNvZ28xAHNvZ28=
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

**From the /var/log/syslog on the server 10.1.2.130**

```
Oct 17 11:21:41 sogo postfix/smtpd[14957]: connect from unknown[172.16.1.8]
Oct 17 11:21:59 sogo postfix/smtpd[14957]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Oct 17 11:21:59 sogo postfix/smtpd[14957]: warning: unknown[172.16.1.8]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

**From the mail server file /etc/saslauthd.conf**

```
ldap_servers: ldap://127.0.0.1:3389/
ldap_version: 3
ldap_auth_method: bind
ldap_search_base: dc=tcusit,dc=com
ldap_filter: (|(uid=%U)(cn=%U))
ldap_scope: sub
```

**From the 10.1.2.130 mail server**

```
root@sogo:~# testsaslauthd -u sogo1 -p sogo
0: OK "Success."
```

Given the testsaslauthd comes back with a "0: OK "Success." tells me that the ldap and saslauthd is working properly.  I know that the POSTFIX/SMTP is using SASL authentication and is failing on the password from the log file.  Postfix/SMTPD is configured with the SASL Authentication and the SASL Authentication through ldap is working given my testsaslauthd test.  What am I missing?  I am just trying to setup a simple mail server that I can use with remote clients from mobile, macs and windows.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: This is old, but I am facing the same issue right now. What was the solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

It´s the solution

1. service saslauthd stop
2. rm -rf /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
3. Edit /etc/default/saslauthd`enter code here`START=yes

DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"

NAME="saslauthd"

MECHANISMS="ldap"

MECH_OPTIONS=""

THREADS=5

OPTIONS="-r -V -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"

1. dpkg-statoverride --force --update --add root sasl 755 /var/spool/postfix/var/run/
2. service saslauthd start